# Why are uses constraints violated when both chains end in the same bundle?

Tags: osgi, jboss7.x, apache-felix

I have four bundles, each containing only a manifest. The bundles are

- `app` which imports `com.example.foo.fragment` and `com.example.bar`
- `foo` which exports `com.example.foo;uses:=com.example.foo.cfg`
- `foo.fragment` which is a fragment attached to `foo` that exports `com.example.foo.fragment` and `com.example.foo.fragment.cfg;uses:=com.example.foo.fragment`
- `bar` which exports `com.example.bar` and imports `com.example.foo`

**Bundle-level dependency graph**:

```
app -> bar
|       |
|       v
|      foo
|       |
v       v
foo.fragment
```

When I install these bundles all at once in JBoss AS 7.2, they work just fine. But if I install the `app` bundle *after* the others, either for the first time or after successfully starting and then uninstalling it, the following uses constraint violation occurs:

```
Caused by: org.osgi.service.resolver.ResolutionException: Uses constraint violation. Unable to resolve resource com.example.app [HostBundleRevision[com.example.app:0.0.
0]] because it is exposed to package 'com.example.foo.fragment' from resources com.example.foo [HostBundleRevision[com.example.foo:0.0.0]] and com.example.foo [HostBund
leRevision[com.example.foo:0.0.0]] via two dependency chains.

Chain 1:
  com.example.app [HostBundleRevision[com.example.app:0.0.0]]
    import: null
     |
    export: osgi.wiring.package=com.example.foo.fragment
  com.example.foo [HostBundleRevision[com.example.foo:0.0.0]]

Chain 2:
  com.example.app [HostBundleRevision[com.example.app:0.0.0]]
    import: null
     |
    export: osgi.wiring.package=com.example.bar; uses:=com.example.foo
  com.example.bar [HostBundleRevision[com.example.bar:0.0.0]]
    import: null
     |
    export: osgi.wiring.package=com.example.foo; uses:=com.example.foo.fragment
    export: osgi.wiring.package=com.example.foo.fragment
  com.example.foo [HostBundleRevision[com.example.foo:0.0.0]]
        at org.apache.felix.resolver.ResolverImpl.checkPackageSpaceConsistency(ResolverImpl.java:1142)
        at org.apache.felix.resolver.ResolverImpl.resolve(ResolverImpl.java:197)
        at org.jboss.osgi.resolver.felix.StatelessResolver.resolve(StatelessResolver.java:56)
        at org.jboss.osgi.framework.internal.ResolverImpl.resolveAndApply(ResolverImpl.java:137)
        at org.jboss.as.osgi.service.BundleLifecycleIntegration$BundleLifecycleImpl.activateDeferredPhase(BundleLifecycleIntegration.java:296)
        ... 31 more
```

The full manifests are:

```
app.jar/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
----------------------------
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-SymbolicName: com.example.app
Import-Package: com.example.foo.fragment,com.example.bar
----------------------------
foo.jar/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
----------------------------
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-SymbolicName: com.example.foo
Export-Package: com.example.foo;uses:="com.example.foo.cfg"
-------------------------------------
foo.fragment.jar/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
-------------------------------------
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-SymbolicName: com.example.foo.fragment
Fragment-Host: com.example.foo
Export-Package: com.example.foo.fragment,com.example.foo.cfg;uses:="co
 m.example.foo.fragment"
----------------------------
bar.jar/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
----------------------------
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-SymbolicName: com.example.bar
Export-Package: com.example.bar;uses:="com.example.foo"
Import-Package: com.example.foo
```

I have not been able to reproduce the above error in standalone Apache Felix 4.2.1.

What is the cause of this behaviour? If I delete the `Fragment-Host: com.example.foo` row from the `foo.fragment` manifest, I can reinstall `app` just fine without errors. Is this a bug in JBoss AS 7.2?

Comment: I agree this is pretty weird. I'm tempted to call this a bug in the JBoss AS framework implementation, in which case it should be reported on the JBoss mailing list and/or issue tracker.

Comment: After monkeying around with it a bit, I noticed that this only occurs if my application is not deployed when JBoss starts up. Maybe there is, after all, another bundle exporting `org.hibernate.annotations`, and the OSGi platform resolves that as the dependency of the Spring ORM bundle if the OSGi platform starts up without my application. Then I deploy my application, and OSGi fails to resolve it because it is not compatible with the `org.hibernate.annotations` bundle resolved to the Spring ORM bundle. Does that sound feasible?

Comment: I have now also started a discussion in the JBoss community: https://community.jboss.org/thread/229824

Comment: @NeilBartlett I just figured out the answer to question 2: the bundle exporting `org.hibernate.annotations` is a fragment with `Fragment-Host: com.springsource.org.hibernate`.

Comment: (The above comments refer to [older versions](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/17317349/4) of the question, it has now been abstracted away from hibernate etc.)

Comment: This looks like a bug. Fragment bundles are supposed to be act as if they are part of their host bundle.It looks like in some cases JBoss is treating the fragment as a separate bundle when performing the classpath consistency check.

Comment: Can you provide us with a zip containing all the jars so that it is easier for us to test? Is this testable in other OSGi containers such as felix?

Comment: @PedroD certainly. It's been a year, though, let me try to reproduce the problem again first. :)

Comment: Phooey, seems like JBoss 7.2 won't compile on my machine, so I don't have a clean instance to run on. I might have time to look into it sometime later. In the meantime [here](https://github.com/emlun/uses-constraints) is a GitHub repo with the example, and [here](https://github.com/emlun/uses-constraints/raw/master/build/distributions/uses-constraints.zip) is a zip file with all the jars.

Regarding other OSGi containers: As stated above, I wasn't able to reproduce this in standalone Apache Felix. I haven't tried other containers.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Constraints from the fragment conflict with the host](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7192247/constraints-from-the-fragment-conflict-with-the-host)

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to import foo.fragment in app your dependency will resolve from foo. so just remove that dependency and re-deploy that. This issue is because of cyclic dependency.

Comment: This is **not a cyclic dependency**. It would be cyclic if foo.fragment depended on app. However, app depends on foo.fragment, so there's no cycle. However, the explicit dependency from app to foo.fragment may be unneeded, that's true.